# Customize leading, trailling, and add shadow on ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make ListTile like this?
[image: What I want]

I try to make but I'm having trouble with the leading (Image) height, the trailing (rating), and the shadow. I know that the best way is to create a custom widget. But I feel using only ListTile it can be done.

[image: What I got]

My code:

```
Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: const Color(0xFF7090B0).withOpacity(0.2),
              blurRadius: 20.0,
              offset: const Offset(0, 10.0),
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          tileColor: kWhiteColor,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
          ),
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          leading: Container(
            width: 70.0,
            height: 70.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
              image: const DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: AssetImage('assets/image_destination6.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Danau Beretan',
            style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: medium,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            'Indonesia',
            style: greyTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: light,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: if you only need a shadow, wrap your `LisTile` with `Card`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some unknown reason, `ListTile` is not provide that much flexibility, or maybe I'm not able to get properly. And thanks @ישו אוהב אותך for giving idea about card.

Full widget on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e079c0e90179393ad27de7c0be132489&null_safety=true)

**Result**

[image]

You can use this **Code**

```dart
Card(
          elevation: 8,
          child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 6),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 70.0,
                        height: 70.0,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/me.jpg',
                            width: 70,
                            height: 70,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 24,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Danau Beretan',
                            // style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
                            //   fontSize: 18.0,
                            //   fontWeight: medium,
                            // ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Indonesia',
                            // style: greyTextStyle.copyWith(
                            //   fontSize: 14.0,
                            //   fontWeight: light,
                            // ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [Icon(Icons.star_half_outlined), Text("4.5")],
                  )
                ],
              )),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

you use Card https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html.

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: const Color(0xFF7090B0).withOpacity(0.2),
        blurRadius: 20.0,
        offset: const Offset(0, 10.0),
      )
    ],
  ),
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.white,
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.5),
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        leading: Container(
          width: 70.0,
          height: 70.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            image: const DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    title: Text(
      'Danau Beretan',
      style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
        fontSize: 18.0,
        fontWeight: medium,
      ),
    ),
    subtitle: Text(
      'Indonesia',
      style: greyTextStyle.copyWith(
        fontSize: 14.0,
        fontWeight: light,
      ),
    ),
  )
),
```